# Split off the [string-split] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone can do many operations on a string, one of them is split.
I don't understand why we should have the [string-split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-split) tag. Having it would legitimate creating "count-string", "replace-string" and many other "*operation*-string" tags.

I think that [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split) are enough to indicate that the post is related to string splitting.

Comment: I'd argue that [tag:split] is a meta tag that should be burninated, instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus But isn't it a reasonable concern about the explosive number of combinatorial tags we might have if every single string-related operation in the world had its own tag? It seems easier to be familiar with a fewer number of tags we can combine and search for `[string][split]` instead of knowing there's a precise tag for this very combo. It also seems equally informative to those who aren't searching specifically for this but just stumble upon a Q with [tag:string] and [tag:split] tags.

Comment: @Ike: I agree, both options are far from optimal.

Comment: I think that having tags for each small detail isn't good for us. Why is this different from "string-even-length" tag?

Comment: I'm looking at it from the standpoint of searching. Forgive my crude analogy, but let's say I'm, uhh, looking for pictures of women in swimsuits on some site. I want to search for like [blonde] then [tall] then [tanned], not go through thousands and thousands of search filters and realize there's a precise one for [tall-tanned-blonde]. :-D There's a lot more search flexibility with a simpler and smaller set of combinatorial tags than an explosive number of self-sufficient, uber-specific tags.